# Wildfly deployment issues: WFLYCTL0288

Tags: java, xml, wildfly

I am having trouble with an installation of Wildfly 9. Before now, everything has been fine and running smoothly. I've since made one small change to standalone.xml (turned up logging level to TRACE for one of the deployed packages, that's it).

Wildfly is running as a service.

Here's what's happening:

1. Made change to standalone.xml
2. Restarted the service
3. Noticed that none of my jars are deploying even though the deployment scanner is on
4. Create .dodeploy files to deploy the jars
5. Every single one fails
6. Change to standalone.xml is reverted, despite clearing the cache

So, I then try to deploy just ojdbc7.jar. This is the error message I am getting:

```
"{\"WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available.\" => {
\"Services that were unable to start:\" => [\"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"ojdbc7.jar\\\".PARSE\"],
\"Services that may be the cause:\" => [
    \"jboss.jdbc-driver.ojdbc7_jar\",
    \"jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector\"
]}}"
```

At first, I thought I may have something else listening on port 8080. I checked, and I definitely don't. I don't really know what else this problem could be.

I am also at a complete loss to explain how my standalone.xml change is not being picked up. It seems like it's cached somewhere and I just don't know where. I have cleared the cache and it just keeps coming back.

Apologies if this seems a little vague - if anyone needs any clarification or more information I'll be happy to oblige.

Comment: How did you deploy the ojdbc7.jar? A bit OT, but it's best to not edit the `standalone.xml` file directory. Changing a logging level should definitely not cause an issue, however you can use CLI or the web console to add or change a level without restart the server.